# Получение случайных чисел в Android

Tags: android, java

Как в Eclipse (программирование под Андроид) получить рандомное число в диапазоне с 5 до 300?

Comment: Причем тут Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Также как и в Java SE:

```
new Random().nextInt(295) + 5;
```

Comment: Если 300 включается, то надо писать `new Random().nextInt(296) + 5;`

Comment: Автор вопроса не добавлял в текст " до 300 включительно" или "не включительно". Главное чтобы понял общую идею, а остальное на практике поймет. Надеюсь.

Comment: Я тоже искренне надеюсь

Comment: Спс, прямо как в Delphi.
Java для меня просто не совсем новый. Большое спасибо.